# can we convert res object in nodejs to JSON?

Tags: node.js

Is there any way to convert `res` object in nodejs to JSON object

```
app.post('/validateUser', function (req, res)
{
    console.log('in post validateUser');
    var usr = req.body.usr;
    var pwd = req.body.pwd;
    //like this 
    callSomeFunctionOrWebservice(JSON.stringify({data:req.body, respVar:res}));
    // the above function gave me error //TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON at

});
```

what I need is to convert the entire thing to JSON, pass the arguments and retrieve the arguments on the other function maybe call a web service

I checked out `flatted`, but I don't know how to encode with `flatted`

I tried this

```
  var flt  = require('flatted');

 //JSON encrypt    
  flt.stringify({data:req.body, respVar:res});
 //JSON parse
  flt.parse(varData);
```

But I couldn't get it to work. Can someone helps me or point me in the correct direction?

Comment: what about res.json() ?

Comment: @DeepKakkar so how should i write it? `callSomeFunctionOrWebservice(JSON.stringify({data:req.body, respVar:res.json()}));`?

Comment: res contains some system objects/handles and can't be passed over network, you must do something like: `res.end(await callSomeFunctionOrWebservice(JSON.stringify({data:req.body, headers:req.headers})));`

Answer (score 0):

You no need convert res to json it is already in json object only.
So

```
var new_object = {data:req.body, respVar:res}

or if you want combine both 

var new_object = {...req.body,...res}

console.log(new_object)
```

Check that it can accessible like json only